# Why am I getting a TypeError with the following Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

This is my code:

```
x = input("Enter a number: ")
print(50/x)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    print(50/x)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Read the error. You're trying to divide an int by a str.

Answer (score 2):

do this

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

as input takes the input in string format

Comment: Now the next question the OP asks will be "Why am I getting a `ValueError`?" after they provide "1.0" for an input.

Comment: because 1.0 is float , for that you need to explicitly convert it

Comment: Haha, yes of course, which I why I pointed that out.  I was trying to hint (perhaps too subtly) that your solution provides no error handling.

Answer (score 0):

input gives `string`, type cast to `int`:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Example:

```
>>> x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
Enter a number: 5
>>> print(50/x)
10
```